# c3p0 and MySql wait_timeout

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I'm getting error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
> No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was
> implicitly closed by the driver

after sometime in my webapp. That "sometime" was 8 hrs but I found out that by default, the server closes the connection after eight hours if nothing has happened. So i changed **"wait_timeout" to 30 sec.** and changed `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period`  property in hibernate.cfg.xml to 10 sec

Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml properties

```
    <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">
       convertToNull
    </property>
    <property>
      name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    </property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">15</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time">18</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
```

Here's my c3p0 properties:

```
c3p0.preferredTestQuery = SELECT 1;
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: configuring c3p0 alone using Spring, and then linking it with hibernate did the trick...not sure why just linking c3p0 properties with hiberate not work....refer to this [link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,139821,160175)  for more details